# Could not load file or assembly oracle.web, version=4.121.1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

I can't run a web application on my development machine because .NET framework could not load assembly `oracle.web version=4.121.1.0`.

Here's the scenario.
The installed version on my machine is 4.112.3.0, correctly registered in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32`.

The offending row in  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` is explicitly requesting

```
type="Oracle.Web.Management.OracleWebEventProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.3.0
```

which is exactly the installed and registered version, so I can't figure out this problem.

Why is .NET trying to load Oracle.Web version=4.121.1.0?

Comment: Is your application 32 bit or 64 bit? Did you register the assembly, or jut paste it in the GAC?

Comment: The application is 32 bit and I registered the assembly in the gac with a tool distributed with the oracle installation

Comment: The offending row is in the healthMonitoring element. Commenting the provider element apperently solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer... but this is what worked for me after tons of research into adding DDLs, modifying the GAC, etc.  Also tried removing Health Monitoring from web.config.
Ensure you **run Visual Studio as Administrator**. This fixed my problem with this!